# Installing Python packages for Jython

Tags: python, netbeans, jython

Can you install Python packages in Jython (Python for Netbeans) with jip?
Jip requires a group ID and an artifact ID, where do I find these?

Comment: `jip` is for installing Java packages. Python packages can be installed with `pip` as usual. I'm not familiar with Jython or Netbeans, but it seems like `pip` is nowadays automatically installed when installing Jython.